# Does the ros2_control's JointGroupPositionController handle velocity constraints?

Tags: control, ros2, urdf

In ROS 1, you could limit the speed that the position controller moved at by specifying a `<limit>` tag within the `<joint>` tag. See [this part of the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20a%20URDF%20in%20Gazebo#Joint_Control)

I'm trying a similar thing in ROS 2, but the `<limit>` tag has no effect, still snapping immediately. [Check out this branch and this section of the partially rewritten tutorial](https://github.com/ros/urdf_sim_tutorial/tree/ros2_devel#joint-control)

Does the ros2_control's JointGroupPositionController handle velocity constraints through the `<joint>` tag or is there something else in the `<ros2_control><joint>` tag that I need to specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately this isn't implemented right now by most of the ros2_controllers (except for, e.g., diff_drive_controller).
But it is on the roadmap as far as I know.

In general, ros2_controllers don't parse the URDF except for the ros2_control tags (admittance controller is again an exception, which needs the kinematics from the URDF): nothing from the `<joint>` tag well be used. But this might change in the future, see this [issue](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/652#issuecomment-1207164456)

Comment: @DLu did that answer your question? If so, please mark the answer :)